# Cannot set div content to bottom

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```
<div class="step-container">
  <div class="step1">
    <button>STEP 1</button>
    <b>Sed leo enim condimentum</b>
    <p>Quisque libero libero, dictum non turpis in, luctus semper lorem. Donec rhoncus a leo sit amet facilisis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want set the content of that div at the botton, so the final result should be this:

[image]

but I get this:

[image]

this is my css:

```
.step-container
{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  top: 854px;
  left: 248px;
}

.step1
{
  background-image: url("pic.png");
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  color: #333333;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `.step1` div try using the following code :

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

You can also add `align-content: flex-end;` (or something else) to handle the space between the elements in your div.

Or put the absolute position and the bottom property on the `.step1`, and the relative position on the `.step-container`.

Comment: the result is not equal as the image

Comment: You'll have to put your own settings on this, like margin etc. With the flex solution, you can set any content to the bottom of his container. Or with the absolute / relative position like @AvcS said.

Comment: but with your solution the button is near the text, in the image all the component are vertically aligned

Comment: Did you add the flex-wrap: wrap; property correctly ? Can you make a fiddle with your code in ?

Answer (score 0):

CSS property bottom works only with positioned elements (relative, absolute or fixed). Please refer to documentation of css position for more information.

```
.step-container
{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.step1
{
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("pic.png");
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  color: #333333;
  bottom:0;
}
```